# Filtering a collection vs. several collections in Backbone?

Tags: backbone.js

When is it appropriate to filter a collection vs. having several collections in Backbone?

For example, consider a music library app. It would have a view for displaying genres and another view for displaying the selected genre's music.

Would you rather make one huge collection with all the music and then filter it or several smaller ones?

Having just one collection would allow you add features for filtering by other attributes as well, but suppose you have tons of music: how do you prevent loading it all in when the application starts if the user if only going to need 1 genre?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the simplest approach is having a common unique Collection that, intelligently, `fetch` an already *filtered by genre* data from the server:

```
// code simplified and no tested
var SongsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Song,
  url: function() {
    return '/songs/' + this.genre;
  },
  initialize: function( opts ){
    this.genre = opts.genre;
  }
});

var mySongsCollection = new SongsCollection({ genre: "rock" });
mySongsCollection.fetch();
```

You have to make this Collection to *re-fetch* data from the server any time the User changes the selected genre:

```
mySongsCollection.genre = "punk";
mySongsCollection.fetch();
```

Comment: This sounds tempting, but what if I need to add another search filter, say, artist name? How do I tell the server that in /songs/elvis the parameter is an artist name, but it /songs/rock it's the genre?
(yes, I'm a total rest-noob)

Comment: You can do this a couple of ways.  The first is to have a separate endpoint for each one, so you'd have /songs/artist/elvis and /songs/genre/rock.  The other way is to use querystring parameters, so you could have /songs/?artist=elvis&genre=rock.  My preference is the first option as it provides cleaner URL's.

Answer (score 1):

It's mostly a design choice, but my vote would be to choose a scheme that loosely reflects the database storing the collections.

If you're likely to be storing data in an SQL database, you will more likely than not have separate tables for `songs` and `genres`. You would probably connect them either via a `genre_id` column in the song table, or (if songs can have more than one genre) in terms of a separate `song_genres` join table. Consequently, you would probably want separate collections representing genres and the songs within them. In this case, **[backbone-relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational)** might be very useful tool for helping keep them straight.

If you're storing information in any kind of relational/key-value/document store, it might make sense to simply store the genre with the song directly and filter accordingly. In this case, you might end up storing your document keys/queries in such a way that you could access songs either directly (e.g., via `songs`) or through the genre (e.g., `genre:genre_id/songs`). If this is the route you go, it may be more convenient to simply create a single huge collection of songs and plan to set up corresponding filters in both the application and database environment.

Comment: Thanks, those sound like solid arguments for making the choice